# Move Back to the Parent View controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I'm currently working on a project that has 3 view controllers. the first View controller presents a list of "Clients". if the Client is "protected", a 2nd View controller (password View Controller) is presented. Once the user enters the correct password, it will then present the 3rd View controller. if the user clicks the Back button from the 3rd View Controller, it should return the user back to the client List and not the Password Box. Same as true if the user clicks the "Unprotected" client, it should present the user the 3rd View controller and not the password Box.

1. Parent View Controller
2. Password View Controller (show if needed)
3. Detail View of the Client

Unfortunately, this code only works without the password VC.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

as this will only return to the Previous VC. These are all presented Modally and is not in a NavController.

Is there a way to dictate or to direct the 3rd view controller to Segue back to the Client List VC Programmatically?

any Help is Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a delegate method in password view controller which is called when password is correct. If password is correct, the delegate method is called and in the parent view controller, it should dismiss password view controller and present the detail view controller.